# Marketing Cloud Custom tracking parameters?

Tags: marketing-cloud

Is there a way we can add our own custom tracking parameter in email templates? Which later we can populate in reports? For example Campaign_ID guid etc ....

Also is there a way to track how many receivers have deleted email without reading and forwarded email (without embedding ET's Forward to friend function).? I tried ET's Forward to friend function but it does not track if user is using client application's function of Forward email.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can use the [**Web Analytics Connector**](https://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/integrated_products__crm_and_web_analytic_solutions/web_analytics_connector/) (WAC) to append whatever parameters you want to all outbound links.  The WAC can include [**personalization strings**](http://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/exacttarget/content/personalization_strings/strings/) and AMPScript variables (e.g. `%%=v(@var1Name)=%%`).

It might be worthwhile to have SFMC Support enable the Additional Email Attributes functionality in the Email Properties page.  I've found that a lot of people use those personalization strings in their WAC configuration.

[image]

As far as I know, there's no way to do any tracking other than clicks and opens after an email has been sent.

In my opinion, any kind of *Forward to a Friend* (FTAF) is murky from an opt-in perspective. You don't want other people opt-ing in their friends to anything, without their permission....unless it's very tightly controlled with a double-opt-in and suppression system. Every single time I've ran across FTAF in a project, it's been abandoned for compliance reasons. I'd recommend against using it at all.

Comment: Is there a way to enable this feature only on particular emails/campaign?

It is enabled on our account but I realize its embedding static parameter to all URLs in all emails. And I can not find an option to enable it on only specific email or links. What I want to do that I want to to have it only on lets say Email X and within email X only on Link Y?

Comment: You cannot disable it on a link-by-link basis without scripting it.  You can disable link tracking per send.  It's a checkbox in the send definition.