# Add parameter on send classification level

Tags: marketing-cloud, url, parameters

Hope you can help me on this question :)

On our website we use a lot of Sleeknote forms, and especially our sign-up forms perform exceptional.

We'd like to hide these forms from all our our newsletter subscribers, and this is possible by adding this parameter to all URLs in the newsletter: **?SNSubscribed=true**

- It would not make sense adding this as a standard parameter (ie. like &utm_source=ExactTarget) to all our sends as our transactional sends often goes to customers who are not yet subscribed.
- It would not make sense either adding that parameter manually to all links as we send approx. 55 million mails pr. year.

But it would make sense if it could be possible to add the parameter based on certain send classifications. To keep this simple; It could be a solution if the parameter was added to all mails sent with a commercial send classification, but to no mails sent with a transactional send classification.

Now that I've explained the background, here goes the question:
*Is it possible to automatically add a parameter to all URLs in mails sent with certain send classifications?*

Thank you

Comment: Why couldn't you use it as a standard parameter - this way you could have it fill with Y or N (based on data extension data) and your LP can read this and react accordingly?

Comment: Hi Gortonington.
This might be a solution! Could be help me by describing this solution a little further? Thank you :)

Comment: Maybe something like adding a parameter to all URLs in all mails:
?SNSubscribed=@SNvalue and then have one AMPScript setting the SNvalue = True in our commercial template and setting the SNvalue = False in our transactional template?

Answer (score 1):

You would likely want to have SFMC turn on the [Web Analytics Connector](https://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/integrated_products__crm_and_web_analytic_solutions/web_analytics_connector/) for you as well as the Additional Email Attributes option to allow you to automatically append a parameter onto every outbound link.

> Use the connector to tag links in your emails by automatically
>   including specific variables in the target URLs. The analytics tool
>   then tracks those URLs back to the email. For example, include the
>   campaign ID in the target URL of your links to identify the web
>   traffic generated by that campaign. When a subscriber clicks a link to
>   your website from your Marketing Cloud email, your web analytics
>   service tracks the activity.

You would also need to make sure that there is a field attached to this person that contains the value of whether they are subscribed or not. In this case, a row named SNSubscribed.

From there you can then have a collector on your web pages that if SNSubscribed = Y then do task else do other task.

Example of Attribute you could use:  `SNSubscribed=%%SNSubscribed%%`

This answer by @AdamSpriggs gives some more details as well: [Marketing Cloud Custom tracking parameters?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/142453/marketing-cloud-custom-tracking-parameters#answer-142562)

Answer (score 0):

I've actually managed to come up with a solution.
It does not fully deliver what I requested in the first place, but it's still extremely useful and handy to us.

I had support add the &SNSubscribed= parameter to every link from our sends, and then I placed this AMPScript in my mail:

```
%%[/*Link Tracking til Sleeknote*/]%% 

<script runat="server" language="ampscript">
var @SNSub, @source
SET @source = "true"
SET @SNSub = @source
</script>
```

A few comments.
1) The setup works like this: SNSubscribed=%%=v(@SNSub)=%%
But to make it work, I had to assign the boolean to an already defined field *(@source is a field in our Data Extension for all subscribers, but the data in the field is never used for anything in our mails)* before reassigning that value to the @SNSub variable.

2) As my template so far always have had a header included in the first content area, I had to rearrange my template as the AMPScript block only assigns the value to all links beneath it in the Email setup part of the Content Builder. By adding the Sleeknote AMPScript block as the first block in the mail setup, the parameter was succesfully added to all links.

[image: The new setup of my template for commercial sends]

@Gortonington - I'm not entirely sure if my solution equals the answer you added, but the answer surely inspired me, THANK YOU :)